# ActionBar search view takes all the space in action bar when active - how to force also other items to show?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-menu

is there a way how to force particular menu item to show even though other item is expanded as actionview?
[image]

I have a searchview and I would like to show also other items at the left from it..Also do you notice those items are actually there, only not visible (hidden behind the border of the screen)?

What is weird that in emulator (800x480) it basically works..It shows an overflow menu next to the actionview, but on nexus 4 it just displays the item as visible on the screenshot..

Comment: yougot the answer or not..??